# Delete / Modify database records from EditorGrid panel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, extjs

I am using ExtJs with Rails 3.x . How to **delete/modify** records from EditorGrid using Ext.Ajax.request method?

I tried using `store.remove()` and similar other methods but it doesn't remove record from database.

Thanks in advance !!

Code :

```
    //** Destroy method **//

         def destroy
            puts 'destroy'
            @unit = Unit.find(params[:id])
            puts 'will destroy'
            @unit.destroy
            puts 'destroyed'
         end

    //** units.js **//

    var delbtn = Ext.getCmp('btnDelete');
                 delbtn.on('click',function(){

                     var grid = Ext.getCmp('maingrid');
                     var selection = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelected();
                     Ext.Ajax.request({
                     url: '/units/destroy',
                     method: 'POST',
                     params: {
                     'id' : selection.data.id }

                    });

                });//end del function

//** Store.js **//
Ext.data.Api.restActions = {
            create  : 'POST',
            read    : 'GET',
            update  : 'PUT',
            destroy : 'DELETE' };
storeId: 'MyUnitStore',
            root: 'data',
            autoLoad: true,
            autoSave: false,
            //batch: true,
            restful:true,
            writer: new Ext.data.JsonWriter({
                encode : false,
                listful:false,

                destroy: '/units/destroy',
                update : '/edit'
            }),
             url: '/units.json',
                fields: [
                {
                    name: 'unitname'
                },
                {
                    name: 'description'
                }
                 ]

//** Edit Button **//
var store = Ext.getCmp('maingrid').getStore();                 
                 store.update();
```

Answer (score 1):

`store.remove()` removes the data (record) from your grid's associated store only. It does not communicate with server side by itself. You need to use the Ajax request and communicate with Rails 3.x to get the appropriate record deleted.

```
var selection = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelected();
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/ExampleController/Delete',
    method: 'POST',
    params: {
        'id': selection.data.id
    },
    success: function(result, request){
        // Refresh the grid store and display
    },
    failure: function(result, request){
        // Display delete error message
    }
}
```

Comment: @abdel : I tried the same, it doesn't display any error but no effect on the button click..

Comment: @rashmi.. nobody can help without looking at your code. Show us what you have done so far.

Comment: @Abdel : oh yes, i've added the code above, the problem is, the url doesn't go to the destroy method of the controller!!

Comment: @rashmi.. unfortunately, I don't develop on rails.. so cannot help with rails

Comment: @rashmi : So... change the url or rails code so that the request goes the correct location?  -- By the way, the other option here is to configure the store with a writer that handles create, read, update, and delete action on store.save().

Comment: @Keylan : I tried usign JSON Writer but still it doesn't go to the url. I have posted the code above again for reference.

Comment: **SELECT `units`.* FROM `units` WHERE `units`.`id` = 10 LIMIT 1** This is what I receive on the console!!

Comment: @rashmi.. what do you mean by 'doesn't go to the url'? Use firebug or chrome developer tool and check your request and response.

Comment: @Abdel: Checked the dev tool on Chrome, nothing is displayed on the console , and if u can see the above comment, the update controller is called but update query is not executed!